# mysql update table columns if one fixed column is duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have multiple columns in a table. I have a unique column, if the entry is duplicate to this column I would like the two columns be updated otherwise insert new row. I am using a separate function in php, but for simplicity I will share the mysql code. In this case col1 is fixed. Insert row if col1 is not duplicate. But this simply inserts a new row even if col1 is duplicate. Also col4 can be null. All the SO questions didn't address my issue.

```
INSERT INTO table1
  (col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES
  ('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  col2=VALUES(col2)
  col3=VALUES(col3)
```

Comment: confirm that you really do have a unique key on col1... you'll never get the `on duplicate` stuff triggering unless a unique key gets violated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work cause you don't have a `UNIQUE` key defined on `col1` column. Per [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Documentation`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) if insertion causes duplicate key violation in `UNIQUE/PrimaryKey` column then `UPDATE` takes place instead if `INSERT`.

So in your case you will have to make `col1` a key column either by defining a primary key / unique key constraint on the column; in order to have it worked.

Comment: that was exactly what happened. Indeed I failed to set the col1 as a unique constraint. Now it is working after I did. Thanks for your help guys.